# Running database in docker container returns error

Tags: docker, mariadb, innodb

I am using docker desktop 20.10.23 on windows, using WSL to create a web-dev environment. When trying to start the `mysqld` service in the docker container I get the following error:

```
2023-04-23  9:35:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
2023-04-23  9:35:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2023-04-23  9:35:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

I have tried checking if other service is using the `aria_log_control` file, and no process was returned. The ownership of the files in `.db/data` is set to the local user, and while in the container, the ownership is set to 1000. No file is present in `var/log/mysql`. I do not know what to try, and I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you mounting volumes?

Comment: Sorry to answer so late, yes, the ./data/db folder is mounted to /var/lib/mysql. And also the ssl certs are mounted, but I think that has no relevance here.

Comment: you have another container or local instance running on the same data directory.